# How do I add a value to nestjs execution context using an annotation

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Assuming I have a controller class with a few methods and I want to annotate a method so that it creates a value in my execution context, is it possible to do that?

```
@Controller('docs')
export class MyController {
  constructor(private readonly service: SubjectsService) {}
   
  ...
  
  @Get('/:Id')
  @MyAnnotation('addThisStringToContext')    <--- something like this?
  async find(@Param() id: string) {
    return await this.service.find(id);
  }
  
  ...

}
```

I tried using decorators, but I couldn't find a way to get execution context inside them.

I've also tried using an interceptor, but i couldn't find out how to pass a value to it.

Answer (score 2):

Decorators cannot add data to an external object (like the ExecutionContext), because they don't act on that object, but on the class, class method, class property, or class method parameter. What you *can* do however, is reflect the value (either using `Reflect` directly, or by using Nest's [`@SetMetadata()`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata) decorator) and then use the `Reflector` class later on (in a guard, interceptor, or filter) and retrieve the value using `this.reflector.get('MetadataKey', context.getHandler()/context.getClass())` (class or handler depending on where the metadata is set). An example could look something like

```js
// app.controller.ts
@Controller('app')
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @UseInterceptor(AppInterceptor)
  @SetMetadata('SomeAnnotatedDecorator', 'this is the value')
  doSomethingForApp(@Req() req) {
    return req.metadataValue;
  }
}

// app.interceptor.ts

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const metaValue = this.reflector.get('SomeAnnotedDecorator', context.getHandler());
    req.metadataValue = metaValue;
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Now if you make a request like

```sh
curl http://localhost:3000/app
```

You should get back the response

```
this is the value
```